# Getting some internal link animation to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that opens a new page and scroll down to a id

```
var jump = function (e) {
 if (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");
 } else {
  var target = location.hash;
 }

 $('html,body').animate(
 {
  scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
 }, 2000, function () {
  location.hash = target;
 });

 }

 $('html, body').hide();

 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

  if (location.hash) {
   setTimeout(function () {
   $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
   jump();
  }, 0);
 } else {
  $('html, body').show();
 }
});
```

What I wanna do is, make it animate the scroll on the current page with internal links. How do I integrate that?

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to just use links, [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hseJL/).

It doesn't require jQuery or javascript, just some elements added to your HTML using IDs as `href` values

```
<a id='exampleTop' href='#exampleMiddle'>I'm an example! Click to go down</a>
```